# Jquery, how to get value of the next of the next element

Tags: jquery, html

i want to get value of the  second element after the input.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 nopadding lines">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> {{$e->title}}
        <small class="desc">/  @if($i->ctype==0) Daily@else Weekly @endif</small>
        <small class="price">{{$e->price}} TL</small>
    </label>
</div>
```

This code iterates in foreach. So i have a lot of this block.
I want to reach price value in success function of ajax.
How can i get this value?

Comment: That's not jQuery. Are you using some templating library?

Comment: `.next().next()` doesnt work? or `.nextAll('.price')`

Comment: @Musa i was tried .next .next, now i will try nextAll

Comment: Juhana, im using template library but this is jquery question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either chain two `.next()` methods:

```
$('input').next().next();
```

or you could use `.nextAll()` and `.eq()` in order to get the second sibling:

```
$('input').nextAll().eq(1);
```

Of course if you know the second element's class, you can specify that as well:

```
$('input').nextAll('.price').first();
```

Comment: console.log($(this).nextAll().eq(1).val()); returns empty line in console. also next().next().val() too

Comment: @yigitozmen The `span` element doesn't have a `value` property, of course the `.val()` method will return undefined.. If you're trying to retrieve the text, use the `.text()` method instead... `$(this).nextAll().eq(1).text()`.

Comment: Croizer  thanks for helping. Now i understand. But i want only get the integer value.. so i have created attribute "valof" inside <small class="price" valof="valuefromvariable"> and i tried to reach it with attr('valof') insteadof text() but it returned me undefined...

Comment: @yigitozmen It appears to work here - https://jsfiddle.net/3ab4u245/ .. if you can reproduce the issue I will check it out.